# How to eliminate the "discard qualifier" warning?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, suppress-warnings

Using GCC and C99 mode, I have a function declared as:

```
void func(float *X);
```

When I call the function, I use a volatile array Y:

```
volatile float Y[2];
int main()
{
    func(Y);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling (with `-Wall`), I get the following warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
blah.c:4: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘volatile float *’
```

I can eliminate it with an explicit `(float *)` type cast, but this repeats in many places in the code.

Is there a way to eliminate this specific warning, with an option or a pragma (or something equivalent)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't turn that warning off.  It's telling you you're violating the type system.  If you want to call `func` you either need to pass it pointers to non-volatile data or change the function signature to accept pointers to volatile data.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually interesting (and arguable, in a way). I don't really change the *type* of the variable. The `volatile` qualifier is a signal for the optimizer. So I wonder why it is regarded as a violation of the type system?!

Comment: In the same way as passing a `const int*` to a function `func(int*)` is a violation of the type system.

Comment: @ysap `volatile`, just like `const`, is part of the type.

Comment: @rubenvb, Jonathan - While accepting your comments, I do see a difference between the `const` and the `volatile` qualifiers. The way I understand it, `const` qualifier gives *compile time* (as opposed to *optimize time*) information about the object. For example, it should prevent me from assigning a value to that object, and I should get a diagnostics if I try to do that. With volatiles, there is no such problem (that I can imagine right now).

Comment: ... but, when you come to think about it, the point may be that the compiler guards from case where a volatile object is passed to a non-volatile function, and that function, having non-volatile arguments, *is* being over-optimized to teh point where the result, per the volatile object, is incorrect!

Comment: So I guess this explanation completes the answer.

Comment: @ysap Could you please explain why a `const` marker is _not_ used in the optimization stage? Specifying that a variable will remain constant is _very valuable_ information during optimization.

Comment: @HonkyTonk - Maybe I was unclear - it *may* certainly be useful for optimization, but it is *definitely* important for compilation, like I mentioned. I cannot see why *volatile* would be important at compile time, though. (In this limited context, I take "compilation" as the translation from C to some low- or intermediate-level representation)

Comment: @HonkyTonk, not as valuable as you might think. On a declaration `const` allows the compiler to put the variable in read-only memory, but on a pointer or reference `const` does **not** mean the variable can't change, only that it can't be changed through that pointer/reference. And if the compiler knows there are no writes to a variable it can optimize its use even if it isn't `const`. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm for more

Comment: Suppose your function is already compiled into a .o or a lib just waiting to be linked to. It may be optimized in ways that suppose non-volatile behavior while the calling code expects the function to treat the variable as volatile.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard allows compilers to do anything they like if a non-qualified pointer is used to access a `volatile`-qualified object.  This allows for platforms where some `volatile`-qualified objects may require special instructions to access them, where e.g. a write via `volatile uint16_t*` might do generate code equivalent to:

```
if ((uintptr_t)ptr >= 0xFFFF0000)
  __outport16(0xFFFF & (uintptr_t)ptr, value);
else
  (uint16_t*)ptr = value;
```

If a compiler writer takes the attitude that compilers should only exploit such freedoms on obscure platforms were doing otherwise would be expensive, and should provide sensible behaviors on platforms where doing so would cost almost nothing, and if the calling code in the original example knows that no outside entities will access `Y` during the execution of `func`, then code targeting that compiler will be able to achieve the required behavior without a diagnostic merely by casting Y's address to a `float*`.  Unfortunately, the people maintaining gcc and clang seem to believe that when the Standard refers to "non-portable or erroneous constructs", it really means "non-portable, i.e. erroneous, constructs" rather than "constructs which are not portable to every single conforming machine in the Universe, and would be erroneous *if such portability were intended*.  Casting the pointer to `float*` will silence the warning on gcc or clang, but I wouldn't count on it causing them to yield sensible code.