# Why is discarding the volatile qualifier in a function call a warning?

Tags: c, warnings, volatile

(Before I start: I know there are [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163969/how-to-eliminate-the-discard-qualifier-warning) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303660/volatile-variables-as-argument-to-function) on this topic, but none I've found answer *why* this is an issue.  I do it regularly and would like to know if I am creating potential problems.)

I'm curious why discarding the volatile qualifier in a function call merits a compiler warning.

The situation is as follows:

```
volatile uint8_t thingy;
void awesome_function(uint8_t *arg);

awesome_function(&thingy); << warning
```

Now, my understanding is that the `volatile` qualifier marks a variable as one that may change in ways outside the compiler's control.  Certain optimisations (most importantly, in my experience, the removal of an 'unused' variable) are thus disabled.

However, if I mark a variable as `volatile`, I am concerned with preventing optimisations in *this scope*.  If I pass the variable down to a function, I am generally happy for standard optimisation to apply within that function.*

This is the case even if the compiler wants to remove the variable from the function (the optimisation I am normally trying to avoid), as even if it does so, it doesn't effect my use of it in *this scope*; the (result of the) function itself is the sequence point (and lvalue) I am interested in.

So, why is discarding the qualifier with respect to function calls a warning, given that it will not enable reordering in the current scope?  Is this because of potential reordering in the called function's scope, which is not allowed for a `volatile` variable?  If so, why is this a problem wrt the current scope?

(* this is normally because such calls are used to start async operations, which will eventually operate on the pointer passed to the function.  That function can do whatever it likes with the pointer, provided it eventually updates it as requested.  The `volatile` qualifier is there to alert the compiler that the local variable will change asynchronously.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The warning here is because the compiler assumes that when you have a pointer to a `volatile` pointer object, that you honestly believe that the pointee value might change from an outside source.  When you pass this pointer into a function that asks for a pointer to a non-`volatile` object, the compiler warns you that the function call might be optimized in a way that doesn't correctly account for the fact that the object might change.

The fact that you know for certain that it's okay to do this means that you might want to put in an explicit cast that removes `volatile`, such as this one:

```
awesome_function((uint8_t*) &thingy);
```

This explicitly tells the compiler "I know that I'm removing `volatile` here, so don't warn me about it."  After all, the whole point of the warning is that you might not have noticed this.

A good analogue would be to think about `const`.  If you have a pointer to a `const` object, you are promising not to modify that object through the pointer.  If you tried passing this pointer into a function that took a pointer to a non-`const` object, you would get a warning because the compiler notices that you might accidentally end up changing the value through the function.  Putting in an explicit cast would be a way to tell the compiler "yes, I know this pointer shouldn't be used to modify things, but I promise I know what I'm doing."

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just want to clarify: you say that the 'function call might be optimized' - do you mean the contents of the function or the call itself?  I would have thought that the latter would not be optimised.  An explicit cast is what I use at the moment (the calls tend to be to start split-phase operations, and I know the variable won't be touched at least until after the call returns).

Comment: @sapi- I meant "the code inside the function might be optimized under the assumption that the object pointed at won't be changed by an external source."  Does that make sense?

Comment: On platforms where I/O registers have a separate address space, casting away "volatile" may sometimes result in a compiler accessing an arbitrary location in memory when it should be accessing an I/O register.  More significantly, I would not trust the authors of "modern" compilers to refrain from abusing the freedoms granted by the Standard to behave in arbitrary fashion without regard for whether any outside entities disturb the storage in question during the execution of the function.

Answer (score 3):

The *reason* for `volatile` is not to prevent optimisations. That's one of the things that may be *done* to a volatile variable, but the *reason* is to indicate to the compiler that the variable may change outside the control of the C "virtual machine", so it shouldn't make too many assumptions about it.

To that end, it's a property of the variable itself rather than the scope of said variable.

If a variable is volatile, passing a pointer to that variable doesn't magically make it non-volatile, it just gives you the address of the volatile variable. That's as it should be.

If you just want to select optimisations based on the scope of a variable, `volatile` is not the tool for the job. You'll have to find some other (likely non-standard) way, such as disabling that specific warning during the cast with `#pragma warning` - this of course will depend on your environment.

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` was originally intended to prevent optimizing out or reordering I/O reads / writes.

For example, if a loop writes a sequence of bytes to a memory-mapped UART transmit register, which appears by default to the compiler to be a memory location of a specified size like any other:

- If these writes were NOT going to an I/O register, it would (usually) make very good sense to optimize the loop and copy **only** the last byte to that memory location.  Or, if there is no external visibility or read accesses of that location, optimize out writes entirely.
- However, as this **is** an I/O register, for correct operation it is required that every byte be written **and** that writes occur in the original order.  It would not be helpful to 'optimize' serial output of `"Test!"` to `"!"` or reorder to `"!tseT"`.

Another example:  reads of a Real-Time Clock register in a 'wait until time X' function.  If the compiler were allowed to optimize out multiple reads, it could read RTC time values into registers once, and then to your `waitUntilTime()` function it would forever be e.g. 1:00:04 PM.

For more, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv or
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile