# C pointer to a const - how to quieten warnings

Tags: c, pointers, constants, xc8

I have an array like this:

```
const uint8_t Translations[] =
{
    0xA6,0xA0,1,0,
    0xA1,0x87,2,0,
    0xA0,0xBE,3,0,
    0,
};
```

and I would like to access it with a pointer:

```
uint8_t * p_translations = Translations;
```

I get the warning:

> warning: assigning to 'uint8_t *' from 'const uint8_t *const' discards qualifiers.

I'm fine with that as I only read from and never write to *p_translations.

Is there a way to quieten the compiler (Microchip XC8) without suppressing warnings?

Comment: Then why not just use `uint8_t const* p_ptranslations` if you never write to it?

Comment: i don't quite understand why you would want to do such a thing since `Translations` is a pointer.
Also is there a reason why you don't make `const uint8_t *p_translations` since you just read this ? 
And possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163969/how-to-eliminate-the-discard-qualifier-warning)

Comment: The best way to *quieten warnings* is to make good code that doesn't issue warnings. In this case follow @Zoso's advice

Comment: @Dzious No, `Translations` is not a pointer. It is an array. In some cases they behave the same but in general they are different things. Beginners should no be confused by such statements.

Comment: yeah my mistake sorry.

Comment: The best way of silencing the warning is writing the correct code . One of the rules : access const objects via pointers to const objects.

Answer (score 3):

There is usually never a good reason to ever discard the `const` qualifier, as the warning states. Some possible reasons in the wild are while passing to APIs that expect raw unqualified pointers. If the API doesn't need to change the data pointed to by the pointer, it should have a `const` in the declaration.

Also, compiler warnings are usually something to aid the developer and are mostly warnings that should be heeded to.

For your case too, there's no reason why `p_translations` should not be a `uint8_t const*` if you never intend to modify what `p_translations` points to. If on the other hand, you *had* to modify `Translations`, then you should drop the `const` altogether from `Translations`. Use `const` to indicate entities that shall remain unchanged throughout the program lifecycle. It's perfectly fine to have a non-`const` array that would be modified, else adopt `const`. [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/204500/275008) is one of many links to read on why `const` can be helpful apart from indicating the `const`-ness of the data, namely possible opportunity for compiler optimizations and avoiding writing code that accidentally modifies the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your pointer `const` too, `const` with pointers mean that the memory region they are pointing to is read-only. That tells compiler that it can do or not do some stuff. In your case(not using const with pointer) compiler understands that as a regular pointer accessing a read-only memory part, and raises a warning, the reason for the warning is you can actually change the `const` variables using pointers, but you should **avoid it at all costs** because it's UB and your program might do stuff that it shouldn't. But when you declare your pointer as `const` it tells compiler to treat it like a `const` and doesn't allow any writing to that memory region. And keep in mind the declaration you use while creating pointer only tells the compiler what type of data you're pointing to. So it doesn't mean your pointer is not changeable. If you want to make your pointer `const` you declare it like this `type* const ptr`. I hope i provided enough help.

Comment: `const` does not mean the pointed-to-memory is read-only. It means a compiler must issue a diagnostic when a program attempts to modify memory through a `const`-qualified lvalue. However, a program may have both a pointers to an object with `const` and pointers to the same object without `const` at the same time, as when a non-`const` pointer is passed to a routine for a `const` pointer. The conversion to `const` pointer does not change the memory to read-only.

Comment: For the most part, the C standard specifies `const` so that it is an aide to avoiding bugs, by catching inadvertent modifications during compilation. It does not provide an enforcement mechanism that can be relied on: Nothing in the C standard requires that the memory of an object defined with `const` be read-only, and it is generally infeasible to do so for objects with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a warning because you store the address of a `const` array into a pointer that is not `const` qualified.

Use `const uint8_t *p_translations = Translations;` to fix the problem.

Note that `const uint8_t *p_translations` is equivalent to `uint8_t const *p_translations`, but different from `uint8_t * const p_translations`, which is a pointer that cannot be changed and points to data that can be changed through the pointer.

Defining `p_translations` as `const uint8_t *p_translations` is a way to tell the compiler that you do not intend to modify the data pointed to by `p_translations` using this pointer.  Since `Translations` is itself defined as `const` data, it should only be manipulated through a `const` qualified pointer to detect code that would try and modify it.